# Cache Busting for Static Files in Blazor 8 Across Different Render Modes

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm working on a Blazor 8 application and I'm having trouble with browser caching of my static files. When I make changes to the CSS files, the changes are not immediately visible because the browser serves the old version of the file from cache.

In ASP.NET Core, I would use the `asp-append-version` tag helper to append a version query string to the URL of the CSS or JS file. This version query string changes whenever the file changes, forcing the browser to download the new version of the file instead of serving the old one from cache.

In Blazor and .NET 8, the general page format is defined in the `App.razor` file. Here's what my `App.razor` file looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bargeh.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/header.js" defer></script>
    <script src="js/bargeh.js" defer></script>
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
@* ReSharper disable Html.PathError *@
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
@* ReSharper restore Html.PathError *@
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I'm referencing several CSS and JS files in the `head` section of the HTML document. I tried manually appending a version query string to the URLs of these files, like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bargeh.css?v=1.0.0">
```

But this approach requires me to manually increment the version number each time I make changes to the CSS file, which is not ideal.

Moreover, my application might use server-side rendering (SSR), server, WebAssembly (WASM), or auto render mode. So, I need a workaround that works for all of these.

Is there a way to automatically append a version query string to the URLs of CSS files in the `App.razor` file of a Blazor.NET 8 application, similar to how `asp-append-version` works in ASP.NET? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Based  on the source codes of [LinkTagHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/LinkTagHelper.cs#L248)

```
if (Href != null)
            {
                var index = output.Attributes.IndexOfName(HrefAttributeName);
                var existingAttribute = output.Attributes[index];
                output.Attributes[index] = new TagHelperAttribute(
                    existingAttribute.Name,
                    FileVersionProvider.AddFileVersionToPath(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase, Href),
                    existingAttribute.ValueStyle);
            }
```

You may try:

Register the required service:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc();
```

Inject IFileVersionProvider

```
@inject IFileVersionProvider fileversionprovider
```

append the version:

```
<head>
    //......
    <base href=@PathBase />
    .....
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
     //......
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src=@FileVersionhref("js/Myjs.js")></script>
</body>
</html>


@code{

    string PathBase="/" ;

    private string FileVersionhref(string path)
    {

        return (fileversionprovider.AddFileVersionToPath(PathBase,path));
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

The implementation class for  `IFileVersionProvider` is `DefaultFileVersionProvider`:

```
internal sealed class DefaultFileVersionProvider : IFileVersionProvider
{
    private const string VersionKey = "v";

    public DefaultFileVersionProvider(
        IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        TagHelperMemoryCacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(hostingEnvironment);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(cacheProvider);

        FileProvider = hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider;
        Cache = cacheProvider.Cache;
    }

    public IFileProvider FileProvider { get; }

    public IMemoryCache Cache { get; }

    public string AddFileVersionToPath(PathString requestPathBase, string path)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(path);

        var resolvedPath = path;

        var queryStringOrFragmentStartIndex = path.AsSpan().IndexOfAny('?', '#');
        if (queryStringOrFragmentStartIndex != -1)
        {
            resolvedPath = path.Substring(0, queryStringOrFragmentStartIndex);
        }

        if (Uri.TryCreate(resolvedPath, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri) && !uri.IsFile)
        {
            // Don't append version if the path is absolute.
            return path;
        }

        if (Cache.TryGetValue<string>(path, out var value) && value is not null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        cacheEntryOptions.AddExpirationToken(FileProvider.Watch(resolvedPath));
        var fileInfo = FileProvider.GetFileInfo(resolvedPath);

        if (!fileInfo.Exists &&
            requestPathBase.HasValue &&
            resolvedPath.StartsWith(requestPathBase.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var requestPathBaseRelativePath = resolvedPath.Substring(requestPathBase.Value.Length);
            cacheEntryOptions.AddExpirationToken(FileProvider.Watch(requestPathBaseRelativePath));
            fileInfo = FileProvider.GetFileInfo(requestPathBaseRelativePath);
        }

        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            value = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(path, VersionKey, GetHashForFile(fileInfo));
        }
        else
        {
            // if the file is not in the current server.
            value = path;
        }

        cacheEntryOptions.SetSize(value.Length * sizeof(char));
        Cache.Set(path, value, cacheEntryOptions);
        return value;
    }

    private static string GetHashForFile(IFileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        using (var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream())
        {
            var hash = SHA256.HashData(readStream);
            return WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(hash);
        }
    }
}
```

You couldn't register it directly due to protection level,and if you select`AddMvc();` method and press F12 check the codes related,you won't find pure solution due to protection level either

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Are you sure that `builder.Services.AddMvc()` is okay in case of performance? Can you explicitly mention the service that you need to add?

Comment: Hi,@Matin,As far as I know,it won't have much influence on performance,and please check what I've updated in my answer ，I don't think there would be a pure solution that only register the required services

Comment: Thanks for looking in the source code. Idk how you did find this. Its again yet another breaking change of updating to .NET 8 Blazor that's probably not documented. With .cshtml one could use `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` and `<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />` afaik. If anybody actually finds it in the documentation, I'm happy to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to get the same effect as using `asp-append-version` is to add the assmembly version to the link tags within the app.razor page as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css?v=@this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()" />
```

Comment: This works if the files change only when the assembly is updated. This solution will not work properly if the wwwroot files are updated independently.